How to power off or suspend a VM and start it again from where it was interrupted
I'm using a virtual machine (Oracle VirtualBox) for Windows 11, in which I have installed Ubuntu.
I tried to power off momentarily the VM but when I reopened it, it forced me reinstalling Ubuntu. I would like to maintain the same VM (with all the files and apps) but to be able to shut it down momentairly in order to save RAM or when I have to restart Windows. I tried on Google but I didn't find a precise answer.
I could make some attempts but I really don't want to have to do it all again if they fail, so I would appreciate if you can breafly teach me how to do it. Thank you.

Are you saying you selected "Power off the machine" instead of "Save the machine state"? If so, then I would recommend the later. See this image.

Yes, I see now. It was a stupid question :D  Thank you for your reply!

If it's bringing you back to the ubuntu installed when you restart, you've probably forgotten to eject the ubuntu install disk
